# Recover data from NTFS partition

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, data-recovery, testdisk

My brother scandisked NTFS partition of my USB HDD. Safe remove didn't work safely. After reattaching the data is missing. Testdisk outputs the following (I have no undelete in Advanced). I run testdisk on ubuntu server with the hdd attached.

How should I restore (recover) the data (partition)?
Those partition types in HEX are pretty weird, there is no 0x87 for NTFS

Testdisk output:

```
Disk /dev/sdb1 - 388 GB / 361 GiB - CHS 47179 255 63
Current partition structure:
     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors

 1 * Sys=4F               120527  49 53 234813 237 34 1836016416

Bad relative sector.
 2 * Sys=73               119380 132 62 153270  41 37  544437093

Bad relative sector.
 3 * Sys=2B               113201  29 24 147074 114 59  544175136

Bad relative sector.
 4 * SpeedStor            177063 118 26 177066 225 63      54974

Bad relative sector.
Only one partition must be bootable
Space conflict between the following two partitions
 3 * Sys=2B               113201  29 24 147074 114 59  544175136
 2 * Sys=73               119380 132 62 153270  41 37  544437093
Space conflict between the following two partitions
 2 * Sys=73               119380 132 62 153270  41 37  544437093
 1 * Sys=4F               120527  49 53 234813 237 34 1836016416
Space conflict between the following two partitions
 1 * Sys=4F               120527  49 53 234813 237 34 1836016416
 4 * SpeedStor            177063 118 26 177066 225 63      54974
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: ... and the question is?

Answer (score 1):

First of all DO AN IMAGE of this drive! I can't stress how important that is. Use [g4l](http://sourceforge.net/projects/g4l/), [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) or just [dd](https://serverfault.com/questions/4906/using-dd-for-disk-cloning).

When you have image work only on that image.

To recover data try open source TestDisk http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk or Recuva from Piriform: http://www.piriform.com/recuva

Comment: Thanks, making an image is great, just need to get a big second HDD. I tried Testdisk, but the outputs are above. I don't know how to change or recover with it

Comment: G4L and clonezilla will allow to compress image. Use gzip as it's quick and efficient. Mind you, some data doesn't compress at all!